# Flutter navigation drawer, navigate push while retaining banner ads

Tags: flutter, widget, admob, ads, banner

How to retain banner ads in Flutter Navigation Drawer while navigating?

In Android Studio Native I can set the banner at MainActivity, hence Fragments navigation does not reload banner ads.

How do you achieve this in Flutter?

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (context) => const SecondScreen()));
```

This will create a new Screen and banner ads gone missing.

home.dart

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(''),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Stack(children: [
          const Center(),
          // TODO: Display a banner when ready
          if (_isBannerAdReady)
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: _bannerAd.size.width.toDouble(),
                height: _bannerAd.size.height.toDouble(),
                child: AdWidget(ad: _bannerAd),
              ),
            ),
        ])),
        drawer: NavBar());
  }
```

nav_bar.dart

```
   class NavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NavBarState createState() => _NavBarState();
}
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      elevation: 10.0,
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey.shade500
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                const CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 40.0,
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: const <Widget>[
                    Text('',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 25.0
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                    Text('',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 14.0
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home ', style: _biggerFont),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (context) => const HomeScreen())
              );
            },
          ),
          const Divider(height: 3.0),
          ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(Icons.warning),
            title: Text('2nd Tab', style: _biggerFont),
            onTap: () {
              // Here you can give your route to navigate
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (context) => const SecondScreen()));
            },
          ),
          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here are my screens:

[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1pwj.png)

[Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aavvv.png)

[Screen 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgTWw.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can not retain a banner ads that was coded at home page in your Second screen. It is because in second screen the widget is not there. As you are navigating to a different page, it is has completely different widgets. To show ads in all your pages in your app, you have to code separately in every page to show your ads.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to Screen 2 image!
Ads in my application were blocked by the admob network because the navigation drawer is on the back page and therefore the advertisement is on it. I have been researching the problem for about 3 months, I did not receive any policy violations during this process. Finally, they responded to my feedback yesterday, they answered the problem with 2 screenshots.
Broblem message "Content that completely or partially blocks the ads served by Google". The navigation drawer hovers over the ad.